# how to display checkbox in hierarchial data display in flex advanced datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

In my advanced datagrid, I am displaying hierachial data. Instead of the folder icon, i need to display a checkbox which i can select or unselect it. Based on the selected checkbox , i need to display the selected cell value. Plz let me know as how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help you: - if you want you can implement your logic in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.ListEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var dpHierarchy:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {Region:"Southwest", categories: [
                    {Region:"Arizona", categories: [ 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Barbara Jennings", Actual:38865, Estimate:40000}, 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Dana Binn", Actual:29885, Estimate:30000}]},  
                    {Region:"Central California", categories: [ 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Joe Smith", Actual:29134, Estimate:30000}]},  
                    {Region:"Nevada", categories: [ 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Bethany Pittman", Actual:52888, Estimate:45000}]},  
                    {Region:"Northern California", categories: [ 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Lauren Ipsum", Actual:38805, Estimate:40000}, 
                        {Territory_Rep:"T.R. Smith", Actual:55498, Estimate:40000}]},  
                    {Region:"Southern California", categories: [ 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Alice Treu", Actual:44985, Estimate:45000}, 
                        {Territory_Rep:"Jane Grove", Actual:44913, Estimate:45000}]}
                ]}
            ]);


            protected function onItemClick(event:ListEvent):void
            {
                myADG_ID.expandItem(myADG_ID.selectedItem,!myADG_ID.isItemOpen(myADG_ID.selectedItem));
            }



        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG_ID" width="100%" height="100%" defaultLeafIcon="{null}" 
                         folderOpenIcon="{OpenCheckBox}" folderClosedIcon="{CloseCheckBox}"
                         itemClick="onItemClick(event)" 
                         displayDisclosureIcon="false"> 
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:HierarchicalData source="{dpHierarchy}" 
                                 childrenField="categories"/>
        </mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Region"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory_Rep"
                                       headerText="Territory Rep"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Actual"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Estimate"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>  
</s:Application>
```

OpenCheckBox.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                                  focusEnabled="true" width="100%" height="100%">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:CheckBox id="cbSelector" selected="true" width="100%" />
</s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
```

CloseCheckBox.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                                  focusEnabled="true" width="100%" height="100%">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:CheckBox id="cbSelector" selected="false" width="100%" />
</s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. But as per your code, for the childnodes checkbox are not getting displayed. Suppose if Arizona has sub regions under it for those nodes checkbox are not there

Comment: Do you mean to say CheckBox at the last child of your Hierarchy? There is no use of CheckBox if that is the last child as user cannot expand it... CheckBox is not visible to last child node as per Hierarchy data is concerned.

Comment: I don't want the checkbox to be displayed at the top node